# Trouble with second conditional special usage

Tags: subjunctive-mood

Lately, I have been asking myself if this sentence was possible:

> If it rained, I would stay at home.

What do you think?

Comment: It sounds correct in a colloquial way, but in front of the Queen I would say *if it **were** to rain...*

Comment: Or *if it **were raining***... Are you talking about the present or the future?

Comment: It is possible t say if it rained... because you don't know how much time it has rained.

Comment: I am talking about the future.

Comment: @SinestroWhite You still use the imperfect subjunctive *if it **were**...* if you're talking about something in the future, it's usually called an 'if clause'

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I am not enough competent and that is why I am asking.

Comment: IIRC, the general rule is: If `<Imperfect Subjunctive>`, `<Conditional>`

Comment: An example of this is *"The doctor **recommend** I stay in bed"*. This is the subjunctive mood in action, even if it is ignored by many native English speakers; usually one would use *recommends* for the 2nd person singular, but the subjunctive tells you to conjugate it with the *recommend* form.

Comment: @BlandorthinTheGrey. In English, he mandative subjunctive (the subject of your last comment) is completely different from the subjunctives used in conditionals, to the point that some grammarians [recommend](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001192.html) they not be called by the same name. Information about one sheds no light whatsoever on the other.

Comment: Ah, I bow to your superior knowledge, do you *recommend* I change my comment? @PeterShor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many linguists (often based outside the US) are quite happy that the past simple may (/should?) be used in such constructions, as this article from [EF Education First Ltd.](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/type-2-conditional/) shows:

> In [what some call] a Type 2 conditional sentence, the tense in the
>   'if' clause is the simple past, and the tense in the main clause is
>   the present conditional or the present continuous conditional.
>
> If clause (condition)...................Main clause (result)
>
> If + simple past ..........................present conditional or
>   present continuous conditional
>
> If this thing happened................that thing would happen.
>
> As in all conditional sentences, the order of the clauses is not
>   fixed. You may have to rearrange the pronouns and adjust punctuation
>   when you change the order of the clauses, but the meaning is
>   identical.
>
> EXAMPLES
>
> If it rained, you would get wet.
>
> You would get wet if it rained.
>
> If you went to bed earlier you wouldn't be so tired.
>
> You wouldn't be so tired if you went to bed earlier.
>
> If she fell, she would hurt herself....

CaGEL (14.2.1) gives the example (and this is handy, as it uses the volitional 'would'):

> I'd cook only if you cleaned up.

The 'if you were to' version sounds highfalutin', at least to many British ears.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible.  It sounds fine to my ear (American), and the tenses also seem to work.

"Rained" is the *Imperfect Subjunctive* verb and "would stay" is the following *Conditional* tense verb.